# Exception when I get response from API (xamarin ios)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working on xamarin forms solution and i want to get result from my API.

I use Dependency Service for this in both projects (android and ios). I have problem only on IOS .

```
    public async Task LoadJson (string url)
    {
        try{
            HttpClient http = new HttpClient ();
            var x = http.GetAsync (new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            string res =await x.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            MainViewModel.JsonList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ArticleClass.RootObject>(res);
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            MainViewModel.JsonList = null;
        }
    }
```

Sometimes I get the following exception :

[image: exception]

Answer (score 0):

My first code working perfect , it's a wifi problem from server not from code.

I post here my new code where i use now for more performance. I add and moderhttpclient from nuget.

```
public async Task LoadJson (string url)
    {
        try{
            using (var http = new HttpClient (new NativeMessageHandler ())) {
                var x = await http.GetAsync (new Uri (url));
                string res = await x.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
                MainViewModel.JsonList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ArticleClass.RootObject> (res);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            MainViewModel.JsonList = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

From the stack trace of the exception, you can read (first 3 lines of your image) is a connection timeout when trying to get the URL.

Comment: The same code works in android . I believe where is something blocking it on ios.

Comment: maybe implementing a simple retry schema in both platforms? In android would not be hitted, but it would help in ios and the code would be similar in both platforms